# About the Two-dimension array address. What does this statement mean？

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[2][3] = {3,5,4,7,9,0};
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<3; j++)
    printf(“%p\n”, *(a+i) +j); // Statment 1
  }
}
```

As you can see，why does the marked statement means it was an address point to the Two-dimension `array[a]`? Doesn't it means that is an value of the `array[a]`? I don't understand if the asterisk means it got value from the (a+i)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example I found on Google

```
int a=9;
int *b = &a;
printf("%p\n",b);
```

On a Win32 system, the following result will be printed:

> 0018FF20

So as you can see that the specifier `p` is used to get the address where the pointer is currently pointing.

```
As a result *(a+i)+j would give you the address where the pointer is pointing in a 2-D array
As a result *(a+0)+0 would give you the 1st row and 1st column address
*(a+0)+1 would give you the 1st row and 2nd column address
*(a+1)+0 would give you the 2nd row and 1st column address.
```